# skipping(going straight to the show page) the index page if there is only 1 item in the database

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

How can I skip the index page and go straight to the show page if there is exactly only 1 project update in my database for that project(while also making sure no button gets displayed if there is no update(zero) in the database?

I tried this:

```
    <% if @project.updates.any? %>  
        <%= button_tag type: "button", :class => "radius" do %>
            <% if @project.updates=1 %>
            <%= link_to 'Project Update', project_update_path(@project),  :style => "color: white" %>
            <% else %>
            <%= link_to 'Project Updates', all_project_updates_path(@project),  :style => "color: white" %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

but i get this error:

```
undefined method `each' for 1:Fixnum
```

On this line:

```
<% if @project.updates=1 %>
```

What is the proper syntax for this?

Below is the relevant code:

My button:

```
<% if @project.updates.any? %>
       <%= button_tag type: "button", :class => "radius" do %>
       <%= link_to 'Project Updates', all_project_updates_path(@project),  :style => "color: white" %>
       <% end %>
<% end %>
```

These is my custom route:

```
    get 'all_project_updates/:id' => 'project_updates#index', as: 'all_project_updates'
```

These are the final generated routes:

```
    project_updates_path     GET     /project_updates(.:format)  project_updates#index
    project_update_path  GET     /project_updates/:id(.:format)  project_updates#show
```

This is my projects controller(show action)

```
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @comments = Comment.all.where(:project_id => @project.id)
    @updates = ProjectUpdate.all.where(:project_id => @project.id)
end
```

And this is my project updates controller index action:

```
   def index
      @projectUpdates = ProjectUpdate.where(:project_id => params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html
      end
   end
```

And this is my project updates controller show action:

```
   def show
      @projectUpdate = ProjectUpdate.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html
      end
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant:

```
<% if @project.updates.count == 1 %>
```

`==` is for comparison, `=` is usually for assignment. Also, you need to compare updates`number to`1`(you can get number with`count`method), not`updates` themselves.

Instead of comparison, you can use [`Enumerable#one?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-one-3F) method:

```
<% if @project.updates.one? %>
```

Comment: Good catch. When I use <% if @project.updates == 1 %> it still takes me to the index page but when I use <% if @project.updates.one? %> it takes me to the show page as desired. Why is the Enumerable method work and the other not?

Comment: @user3597950 because of my mistake (you should compare `updates` count to `1`, not update themselves. Check my answer after edition.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot. Last question, why does @project.updates == 1 not work? while using .count does? What is it comparing to in each instance? I am not sure I have understood that quite yet still learning.

Comment: @user3597950 simply because `@project.updates` is something different than `1`.

Comment: @user3597950 it's `ActiveRecord::Relation`, a kind of sophisticated `Array`.

Comment: do you know where the best place to read/learn about ActiveRecord:Relation's would be? It's a concept I haven't gotten quite grasped

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
I guess it would be good.